# How to always keep the first cell in the first position

Tags: swift, uitableview

How to always keep the first cell in the first position, so in case it's required to reorder the other cells the first one cannot be moved.

Comment: What have you tried and what isn't working? If you haven't tried anything yet, have a look at `canMoveRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: If you always to show the first cell at the top you can put that content in the 'tableHeaderView' in that it don't go in reorder also

Answer (score 0):

try this. editing will be disabled for forst row and for other rows editing is enabled.

//swift code

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
           return false
        }
        return true
    }
```

//Objective-C code

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:   (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     if (indexPath.row == 0) {
      return true;
     }
     return false;
}
```